# Is it possible to style an custom element of Polymer with an external css file

Tags: css, polymer

Is it possible to style a custom element with an external css file that is linked on the index page but not in an element itself. I haven't found any documentation about using a css file not within the element itself.

I have something like this example.

```
<head>

/* Use of only 1 css for all elements */
<link href="css/custom.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>

<my-element></my-element>

<my-other></my-other>
<my-other2></my-other>

</body>
```

The problem is that the styling has been done in Firefox but not in Chrome.
So I know it's not a problem with the css.

Css looks something like this.

```
my-element {
    header {
        background-color: @article-color;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 25px;

        h1 {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    }
}

/* Styling of other elements */
```

I know I can use css within the polymer element itself, but I don't want to do this. I have multiple elements and I want to style all of them within one css file that I link in the index file like in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to style custom elements from the index file using a `::shadow` or the `/deep/` pseudo-element.

Example:

```
<head>
<style>
// This is thinking there is a 'p' in 'my-element'
my-element::shadow p{
 color: red
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<my-element></my-element>

</body>
```

But please know this before you use it,according to the Polymer docs this method is not very efficient in execution, meaning it could potentially slow the rendering of the page if used a lot.

More info about `::shadow` and Styling Custom elements at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/styling.html

Comment: I tested the difference from styling inside the element or external and there is indeed a noticeable loading difference. So I will place my css inside the element.